# Parsing a token with hyphen in Jinja

Tags: jinja2

I have a token which has hyphen in it and I am trying to read it in jinja, Here is the sample code:

```
{
  [
    {
        {% for curPool in data.pool %}                  
            "name": "{{curPool.name}}",
            "my-org":"{{curPool.my-org}}"           
        {% endfor %}
    }
  ]
}
```

The variable curPool has two fields: name and my-org ( i have no choice of defining these tokens)

When I run this code, I get an error:

> Can't render, error: 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Undefined' and 'Undefined''

It seems to me that it does not know how to parse the hyphen in the token name. I have tried to escape it with '\', ''', and a '%'. But nothing works. Would appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) can be used:

> `"my-org":"{{curPool.get('my-org')}}"`

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful in working with a dict key in Ansible with a hyphen; `{{ ansible_facts.packages.made-up-pkg-name }}` was not working, but `{{ ansible_facts.packages.get('made-up-pkg-name') }}` worked.